# Member 'observe' cannot be used on value of protocol type; use generic constraint instead

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to observe a property (which is declared within an Objective-C) in Swift.

Objective-C protocol:

```
@protocol DemoViewModel <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bla;
@end
```

Swift observe:

```
@objc public dynamic var vm: (NSObject & DemoViewModel) {
   didSet {
        vm.observe(#keyPath(DemoViewModel.bla)) { _,_ in
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly I receive an error:
`Member ‘observe’ cannot be used on value of protocol type ‘NSObject & DemoViewModel’; use a generic constraint instead`

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There must be something special under the hood about the `observe` function, since all the functions and methods can be accessed your way. It's asking you to instead create something like this:

```
class Foo {
    @objc public dynamic var vm: (NSObject & DemoViewModel)?

    private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    func setVM<T>(_ vm: T) where T: NSObject &: DemoViewModel {
        self.vm = vm
        observer = vm?.observe(\.bla, options: [.old, .new]) { _, _ in
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

When you implement `DemoViewModel`, remember that you need to mark `bla` as `dynamic`, otherwise the observer won't be called.

```
class Bar: NSObject, DemoViewModel {
    @objc dynamic var bla: String = ""
}
```